# Animating a canvas element using async data

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, async-await

I want to draw a rectangle on an HTML5 `canvas`, and have it move based on coordinates originating from an asynchronous source. I used `setTimeOut` to simulate the asynchronous source:

```
async function getX() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(Math.random() * canvas.width);
         }, 500);
    });
}
async function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    const x = await getX();
    ctx.strokeRect(x, 100, 200, 100);
}

animate();
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Trying to draw it without animating (i.e. - without using `requestAnimationFrame()`), works, so I believe the problem arises from some "collision" between frames wanting to move forward and the async function.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a race condition between requestAnimationFrame(animate) which calls animate before the next frame and getX which stalls the method for 500 ms. Resulting in ctx.clearRect being called at least one time before each frame.

You can avoid the race condition by rearranging your code like this:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Async Animation</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    <script>
        const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        async function getX() {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(Math.random() * canvas.width);
                }, 500);
            });
        }

        async function animate() {
            const x = await getX();

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.strokeRect(x, 100, 200, 100);

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }

        animate();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @MichaelHaddad This makes the requestAnimationFrame wait for the result, that technically makes the loop synchronous... if there are multiple sources that you have to do the same `await` the delay will be significant

Answer (score 2):

I would use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` that should simplify a lot in your code, also you are already using global variables I would add those animated elements as global too...

Here is an example: *(with a bit more complexity)*

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('x');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var bricks = [ {x:10, y:100}, {x:10, y:50}, {x:10, y:10} ]
var circle = {x:100, y:90}

function updateBricks() {
  bricks.forEach((b) => {
    b.x = Math.random() * canvas.width
  })
}

function updateCircle() {
  circle.y += 2
  if (circle.y > canvas.height)
    circle.y = 0
}

function animate() {    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath()
    bricks.forEach((b) => {
      ctx.strokeRect(b.x, b.y, 40, 20);
    })
    ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

setInterval(updateBricks, 800);
setInterval(updateCircle, 100);
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="x" ></canvas>
```

You can see see I have two variables `bricks` and `circle`, I still do all the drawing like you in the animate function, but I added a couple of new functions to update the position of the elements, and those are called at different intervals.

The same logic can be applied to other asynchronous input; use global variables for the elements and modify the position at own pace, it could be user input or the response from an api call

---

Below is another example, using the same principle I added a new global variable (beer), in this example when the circle hits the bottom of the canvas I make an api call to get a random beer name and display that for two seconds.

You can see that all animations are playing together nicely, everything still getting drawn in the animate function, and no `await` in that function or that will pause the `requestAnimationFrame` loop

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('x');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "40px Arial";

var bricks = [{x: 10, y: 100}, {x: 10, y: 50}, {x: 10, y: 10}]
var circle = {x: 100,  y: 90}
var beer = ""

function getBeer() {
  fetch("https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/beers")
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      beer = data.name;
      setTimeout(() => {beer = ""}, 2000)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}

function updateBricks() {
  bricks.forEach((b) => {
    b.x = Math.random() * canvas.width
  })
}

function updateCircle() {
  circle.y += 2
  circle.x = Math.sin(circle.y/5)*20 + 100
  if (circle.y > canvas.height) {
    circle.y = 0
    getBeer()
  }
}


function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath()
  bricks.forEach((b) => {
    ctx.strokeRect(b.x, b.y, 40, 20);
  })
  ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  if (beer) 
    ctx.strokeText(beer, 10, 60)
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

setInterval(updateBricks, 800);
setInterval(updateCircle, 100);
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="x"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. I used `setTimeout` only for demo purposes. The actual code gets the value of `x` asynchronously from an external source, without using `setTimeout`.

Comment: @MichaelHaddad I mentioned in my answer ... same logic can be applied to other asynchronous input; use global variables for the elements and modify the position at own pace, it could be user input or the response from an api call

Comment: @MichaelHaddad I added a second example to my answer that gets a value (a beer name) asynchronously from an external source